# PHP How does the string go to XML?

Tags: php, xml

How does the string go to XML?

I use PHP to edit

I have a string of data but I can not figure out how to turn XML data:

```
<?php
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/BodyPartExteriorFinish-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1/AutoPart-1";

$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1/AutoPart-1/ModelYear-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1/AutoPart-1/Voltage-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1/AutoPart-1/ModelName-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1/AutoPart-1/ColorSpecification-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1/AutoPart-1/ColorSpecification-1/Color-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1/AutoPart-1/ColorSpecification-1/ColorMap-1";
?>
```

How do I turn the string into it?

```
<AutoAccessory>
    <ProductType>
        <AutoPart>
            <ModelYear></ModelYear>
            <ColorSpecification>
            <Color></Color>
            <ColorMap></ColorMap>
            </ColorSpecification>
        </AutoPart>
    </ProductType>
</AutoAccessory>
```

I can not think of methods
Who can help me or give me some ideas
I will be very grateful 
Thanks

Comment: It's going to involve some parsing and re-writing. What have you tried?

Comment: I try to turn information into Array ( [1] => AutoAccessory [2] => ProductType [3] => AutoPart [4] => ModelYear,Voltage,ModelName,ColorSpecification [5] => Color,ColorMap )

Comment: I do not know how to turn the array into  array(  
    "AutoAccessory" =>array(
     "ProductType"=>array("AutoPart"=>array("ModelYear"=>2017,
               "Voltage"=>"",
               "ModelName"=>"",
               "ColorSpecification"=>array("Color"=>"RED",
                      "ColorMap"=>"RED"
                 
                 
                      )
          
                )
          )
     
     
     
     
     )  
);

Comment: If can turn success ARRAY    ,     I can turn to XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE^E_WARNING);

$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/BodyPartExteriorFinish-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1/AutoPart-1";

$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1/AutoPart-1/ModelYear-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1/AutoPart-1/Voltage-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1/AutoPart-1/ModelName-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1/AutoPart-1/ColorSpecification-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1/AutoPart-1/ColorSpecification-1/Color-1";
$A_array[]="/AutoAccessory-1/ProductType-1/AutoPart-1/ColorSpecification-1/ColorMap-1";

$str_array=array('-1'=>'' );

foreach($A_array as $AA =>$AA_val){
    //Remove left blank
    $Barray[] =strtr( ltrim($A_array[$AA],'/'), $str_array );


}

//print_r($Barray);


///////////////////////////////////////
foreach($Barray as $Bbb =>$B_val){
    //String to the array
$CTG_array[] = explode('/',$Barray[$Bbb]);
}

//print_r($CTG_array);


///////////////////////////////////////

foreach($CTG_array as $Ccc =>$C_val){
    //print_r($CTG_array[$Ccc]);
    //if Number of layers
    if(count($CTG_array[$Ccc])==1){

        $sum_array[] =array($CTG_array[$Ccc][0]=>'');
    }   
    if(count($CTG_array[$Ccc])==2){
        $sum_array[] =array($CTG_array[$Ccc][0]=>array($CTG_array[$Ccc][1]=>''));
    }

    if(count($CTG_array[$Ccc])==3){
        $sum_array[] =array($CTG_array[$Ccc][0]=>array($CTG_array[$Ccc][1]=>array($CTG_array[$Ccc][2]=>'')));
    }   

    if(count($CTG_array[$Ccc])==4){
        $sum_array[] =array($CTG_array[$Ccc][0]=>
                          array($CTG_array[$Ccc][1]=>
                                array($CTG_array[$Ccc][2]=>
                                      array($CTG_array[$Ccc][3]=>'')
                                     )
                               )
                         );
    }

    if(count($CTG_array[$Ccc])==5){
        $sum_array[] =array($CTG_array[$Ccc][0]=>
                          array($CTG_array[$Ccc][1]=>
                                array($CTG_array[$Ccc][2]=>
                                      array($CTG_array[$Ccc][3]=>
                                            array($CTG_array[$Ccc][4]=>'')
                                           )
                                     )
                               )
                         );
    }

    if(count($CTG_array[$Ccc])==6){
        $sum_array[] =array($CTG_array[$Ccc][0]=>
                          array($CTG_array[$Ccc][1]=>
                                array($CTG_array[$Ccc][2]=>
                                      array($CTG_array[$Ccc][3]=>
                                            array($CTG_array[$Ccc][4]=>
                                                  array($CTG_array[$Ccc][5]=>'')
                                                 )
                                           )
                                     )
                               )
                         );
    }


    if(count($CTG_array[$Ccc])==7){
        $sum_array[] =array($CTG_array[$Ccc][0]=>
                          array($CTG_array[$Ccc][1]=>
                                array($CTG_array[$Ccc][2]=>
                                      array($CTG_array[$Ccc][3]=>
                                            array($CTG_array[$Ccc][4]=>
                                                  array($CTG_array[$Ccc][5]=>
                                                        array($CTG_array[$Ccc][6]=>'')
                                                       )
                                                 )
                                           )
                                     )
                               )
                         );
    }   

    if(count($CTG_array[$Ccc])==7){
        $sum_array[] =array($CTG_array[$Ccc][0]=>
                          array($CTG_array[$Ccc][1]=>
                                array($CTG_array[$Ccc][2]=>
                                      array($CTG_array[$Ccc][3]=>
                                            array($CTG_array[$Ccc][4]=>
                                                  array($CTG_array[$Ccc][5]=>
                                                        array($CTG_array[$Ccc][6]=>
                                                              array($CTG_array[$Ccc][7]=>'')
                                                             )
                                                       )
                                                 )
                                           )
                                     )
                               )
                         );
    }       


    if(count($CTG_array[$Ccc])==8){
        $sum_array[] =array($CTG_array[$Ccc][0]=>
                          array($CTG_array[$Ccc][1]=>
                                array($CTG_array[$Ccc][2]=>
                                      array($CTG_array[$Ccc][3]=>
                                            array($CTG_array[$Ccc][4]=>
                                                  array($CTG_array[$Ccc][5]=>
                                                        array($CTG_array[$Ccc][6]=>
                                                              array($CTG_array[$Ccc][7]=>
                                                                    array($CTG_array[$Ccc][8]=>'')
                                                                   )
                                                             )
                                                       )
                                                 )
                                           )
                                     )
                               )
                         );
    }   



}


//print_r($sum_array);
$array_sum =array();
foreach($sum_array as $count_int =>$count_str){

    $array_sum = array_merge_recursive($array_sum,$sum_array[$count_int]);

}
//print_r($array_sum);

//array Merge example
/*
$sum_array = array('AutoAccessory'=>'');
$sum_array2 = array('AutoAccessory'=>array('BodyPartExteriorFinish'=>''));
$sum_array3 = array('AutoAccessory'=>array('ProductType'=>''));
$sum_array4 = array('AutoAccessory'=>array('ProductType'=>array('AutoPart'=>'')));
$sum_array5 = array('AutoAccessory'=>array('ProductType'=>array('AutoPart'=>array('ModelYear'=>''))));
$sum_array6 = array('AutoAccessory'=>array('ProductType'=>array('AutoPart'=>array('Voltage'=>''))));
$sum_array7 = array('AutoAccessory'=>array('ProductType'=>array('AutoPart'=>array('ModelName'=>''))));
$sum_array8 = array('AutoAccessory'=>array('ProductType'=>array('AutoPart'=>array('ColorSpecification'=>''))));

print_r(array_merge_recursive($sum_array,$sum_array2,$sum_array3,$sum_array4,$sum_array5,$sum_array6,$sum_array7,$sum_array8));
*/




class A2Xml {  
    private $version    = '1.0';  
    private $encoding   = 'UTF-8';  
    private $root       = 'ProductData';  
    private $xml        = null;  
    function __construct() {  
        $this->xml = new XmlWriter();  
    }  
    function toXml($data, $eIsArray=FALSE) {  
        if(!$eIsArray) {  
            $this->xml->openMemory();  
            $this->xml->startDocument($this->version, $this->encoding);  
            $this->xml->startElement($this->root);  
        }  
        foreach($data as $key => $value){  
            if(is_array($value)){  
                $this->xml->startElement($key);  
                $this->toXml($value, TRUE);  
                $this->xml->endElement();  
                continue;  
            }  
            $this->xml->writeElement($key, $value);  
        }  
        if(!$eIsArray) {  
            $this->xml->endElement();  
            return $this->xml->outputMemory(true);  
        }  
    }  
}  
//array to XML
$xml = new A2Xml();  
echo $xml->toXml($array_sum);  



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At present I turn into array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => AutoAccessory ) [1] => Array ( [0] => AutoAccessory [1] => BodyPartExteriorFinish ) [2] => Array ( [0] => AutoAccessory [1] => ProductType ) [3] => Array ( [0] => AutoAccessory [1] => ProductType [2] => AutoPart ) [4] => Array ( [0] => AutoAccessory [1] => ProductType [2] => AutoPart [3] => ModelYear ) [5] => Array ( [0] => AutoAccessory [1] => ProductType [2] => AutoPart [3] => Voltage ) [6] => Array ( [0] => AutoAccessory [1] => ProductType [2] => AutoPart [3] => ModelName ) [7] => Array ( [0] => AutoAccessory [1] => ProductType [2] => AutoPart [3] => ColorSpecification ) [8] => Array ( [0] => AutoAccessory [1] => ProductType [2] => AutoPart [3] => ColorSpecification [4] => Color ) [9] => Array ( [0] => AutoAccessory [1] => ProductType [2] => AutoPart [3] => ColorSpecification [4] => ColorMap ) )
```

But I do not know how to turn it into

```
$res = array(  
"AutoAccessory" =>array(
                "BodyPartExteriorFinish"=>"",
                "ProductType"=>array("AutoPart"=>array("ModelYear"=>2017,
                                                        "Voltage"=>"",
                                                        "ModelName"=>"",
                                                        "ColorSpecification"=>array("Color"=>"RED",
                                                                                    "ColorMap"=>"RED"


                                                                                    )

                                                      )
                                    )




                )
```

);

If successfully turned into the above array 
Use the following program to output XML

```
        class A2Xml {  
    private $version    = '1.0';  
    private $encoding   = 'UTF-8';  
    private $root       = 'ProductData';  
    private $xml        = null;  
    function __construct() {  
        $this->xml = new XmlWriter();  
    }  
    function toXml($data, $eIsArray=FALSE) {  
        if(!$eIsArray) {  
            $this->xml->openMemory();  
            $this->xml->startDocument($this->version, $this->encoding);  
            $this->xml->startElement($this->root);  
        }  
        foreach($data as $key => $value){  
            if(is_array($value)){  
                $this->xml->startElement($key);  
                $this->toXml($value, TRUE);  
                $this->xml->endElement();  
                continue;  
            }  
            $this->xml->writeElement($key, $value);  
        }  
        if(!$eIsArray) {  
            $this->xml->endElement();  
            return $this->xml->outputMemory(true);  
        }  
    }  
}  
$res = array(  
    "AutoAccessory" =>array(
                    "ProductType"=>array("AutoPart"=>array("ModelYear"=>2017,
                                                            "Voltage"=>"",
                                                            "ModelName"=>"",
                                                            "ColorSpecification"=>array("Color"=>"RED",
                                                                                        "ColorMap"=>"RED"


                                                                                        )

                                                          )
                                        )




                    )  
);  
$xml = new A2Xml();  
echo $xml->toXml($res);
```